# RDP in web application

Tags: asp.net, remote-desktop, remote-access

ASP.NET : is there a way to use rdp in my web application?I need to create asp.net application and open remote desktop from my pc to another one though my web page

Answer (score 2):

You can also check [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), which is similar to [Guacamole](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client), but for Windows.

PS: Myrtille is the open source incarnation of Steemind cited above. I just saw the comment as I write these lines. @lopsided: please apologize my high latency reply.

Answer (score 1):

Here, We have created new rdp file with dynamic IP address to mentioned path and the same will be downloaded by using HttpResponseMessage

**API Controller**

```
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SafeIntranet.Controllers
{
  public class RemoteDesktopController : Controller
  {

     public HttpResponseMessage GetRDPFileDownload(string ipAddress)
     {
         string filePath = @"C:\Test\AzureVMFile.rdp";

         if (File.Exists(filePath))
         {
             File.Delete(filePath);
         }
         using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filePath))
         {
             Byte[] title = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("full address:s:" + ipAddress + ":3389 \nprompt for credentials:i:1 \nadministrative session:i:1");
             fs.Write(title, 0, title.Length);
         }
         MemoryStream dataStream = null;
         var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
         dataStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);

         HttpResponseMessage HttpResponseMessage = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
         HttpResponseMessage.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
         HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
         HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "AzureVM.rdp";
         HttpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
         return HttpResponseMessage;
     }
   }
 }
```

**Client Side Code:**

```
window.location.href = "https:\\api.test.com\v1\azure\GetRDPFileDownload?ipAddress=10.10.10.10";
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any way you can launch RDP from asp.net and relay it through the browser, there are other remoting solution that are web based, you can check out:

GoTo My PC: http://www.gotomypc.com/
and
LogMeIn: http://www.logmein.com/

If you don't need a GUI but need your ASP.NET to execute remote code on the other server you can probably use PowerShell's remoting features:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819505.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do believe Window server already supports this you just need to install the RDP remote application watch this youtube to find out how to install http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S6CIAGfcTU8&feature=related

info http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KKtTw5RTCc

Answer (score 0):

Pass this code to an HTML File and if you want you can divide it later no an ASP.net aspx file separating the HTML and Code Behind.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Check out the minimal requirements to client machine.

Good Programming ! fellow "blue color workers" of the digital world ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link which will download an automatically generated .rdp file in ASP.Net MVC using a simple controller.

Create a controller:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace SafeIntranet.Controllers
{
    public class RemoteDesktopController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string link)
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= " + link + ".rdp");

            return new FileContentResult(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"full address:s: {link}"), 
                "application/rdp");
        }
    }
}
```

Create a link to call this in you view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("RemoteMachineName", "Index", "RemoteDesktop", new { link = "RemoteMachineName" }, null)
```

Or:

```
<a href="RemoteDesktop/Index?link=RemoteMachineName">RemoteMachineName</a>
```